# Mocking Reactotron for Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, reactotron

I have set up Reactotron with almost default configuration:

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';

const reactotron = Reactotron
  .configure()
  .useReactNative()
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect();

export default reactotron;
```

And imported it in 'index.js':

```
if (__DEV__) { import('./app/utils/reactotron'); }
```

But after this, most of Jest tests are failed with the next error:

```
ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

   8 |   .useReactNative()
   9 |   .use(reactotronRedux())
> 10 |   .connect();
     | ^
  11 | 
  12 | export default reactotron;

  at createSocket (node_modules/reactotron-react-native/dist/index.js:1:13571)
  at a.value (node_modules/reactotron-core-client/dist/index.js:1:8397)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/utils/reactotron.js:10:1)
```

It looks like I need to add WebSocket or something else to global variables for tests, but should I do it for all tests or there is any way to make it once for all tests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appeared that for such cases we need to mock the `reactotron-react-native` package. So to solve it just put a `__mocks__` folder into your root folder and add there file with the same name as package. So for this case it will be 'reactotron-react-native.js'. This file should mock all functions from the package. For me helped next one:

```
const reactotron = {
  configure: () => reactotron,
  useReactNative: () => reactotron,
  use: () => reactotron,
  connect: () => reactotron,
};

module.exports = reactotron;
```

In this case it allows chaining of the functions, so the order of calls in tests can be changed.

Comment: To make this work in my case, the directory had to be `__mocks__`. Not sure what the difference is, but noting this in case someone else has that issue.

Comment: @DonBranson you are completely right, in my case it's __mocks__ as well. Let me update the answer

Comment: In fact it was with underscores, but StackOverflow treated it as bold font =)